# How to install only one function from an npm package?

Tags: typescript, npm

not sure if I'm presenting the correct syntax below, but how can I add to my own npm package the ability to install not the whole package, but just one function when installing? Like this:

`npm install import {utility} from "myPackage/utilities"`

Comment: Why do you need that? even if entire package is downloaded Webpack (or any similar tool) will bundle only used part of that package.

Comment: you do exactly what you want but within the project files not npm. NPM downloads the package and it is not designed to know the dependencies within the package